# Color the text of ol in red

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have the following list :

[image]

I want to color the elements of the ol list in red, this is what I did :

```
<ol type="I" style='color: red;'>

  <li>Mathématiques appliquées 1
  <ul> Mathématiques appliquée 1
  <ul>
  <li> Cours:2h </li>
  <li> TD: 1h </li>
  </ul>
  </ul>
  </li>
   
  <ul> Atelier Mathématiques appliquées1
  <ul>
  <li> TP: 1.5h </li> 
  </ul>
  </ul>
  
</ol>

<ol type="I">
<li>Algorithmique et structures de données
  <ul> Algorithmique et structure de données 1
  </ul>
  </li>
```

This is what I get when I add color red to ol:

[image]

Comment: color is inherited, you need to reset it on child

Comment: `ol{color:red;} ul{color:initial;}` ....

Comment: it's not clear what you're asking and your code is incomplete.

Comment: @devsandbox how is it not clear what he is asking? he has 1 image addes making it avbsolutly clear that he tries to change the color of level 1 list without inheritance. He also provided more code then necessary. For that question alone, code would not be needed.

Comment: @tacoshy it's not clear. He says "I want to color the elements of the ol list in red". What elements? All of them? if not, which ones? His HTML is also missing closing tags and this question is poorly worded. Not to mention your comment is full of typos :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'am added a

```
 ol > li {
color: red
}

ol li ul{
  color: black;
}

ul li {
  color: blue;
}
```

For changed a color into text

**Example**

```css
ol > li {
color: red
}

ol li ul{
  color: black;
}

ul li {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ol type="I">
    <li id="li1">Mathématiques appliquées 1</li>
    <ul> Mathématiques appliquée 1<ul>
    <li> Cours:2h </li>
    <li> TD: 1h </li>
    </ul>
    </ul>
    </li>
     
    <ul> Atelier Mathématiques appliquées1
    <ul>
    <li> TP: 1.5h </li> 
    </ul>
    </ul>
    
  </ol>
  
<ol type="I">
  <li id="li1">Algorithmique et structures de données
    <ul> Algorithmique et structure de données 1</ul>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    #li1{
        color: red;
    }
</style>
```

put this in your `<head>`.
and this in your `<body>`

```
<ol type="I">
    <li id="li1">Mathématiques appliquées 1</li>
    <ul> Mathématiques appliquée 1
    <ul>
    <li> Cours:2h </li>
    <li> TD: 1h </li>
    </ul>
    </ul>
    </li>
     
    <ul> Atelier Mathématiques appliquées1
    <ul>
    <li> TP: 1.5h </li> 
    </ul>
    </ul>
    
  </ol>
  
  <ol type="I">
  <li id="li1">Algorithmique et structures de données
    <ul> Algorithmique et structure de données 1
    </ul>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: If him need a list for blue color in 2nd Li, how to change color to blue?

Comment: Give ```<li id="li2">``` wherever you want to change color to blue and put    #li2 {color : blue;}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       in ```<style>```.

Comment: If so, it will use too much css code. If there is a way that is more minimal maybe it can be used.

Comment: You can use inline CSS for each item instead to reduce lines of code.